# Set admin account using Meteor to view all tasks

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteor-accounts, alanning-roles

I'm new to Meteor and just walked through the To-Do list tutorial available here (https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app). I removed autopublish and set the display function in such a way that all tasks were private (that is, users could see only see their own tasks.)

Now, I'd like to change it up and set one account as an admin account. The admin can view everyone's tasks, but no one else can see anything (not even their own tasks). I'm trying to do this using the alanning-roles package, which I already downloaded in the app folder.

In my tasks.js file, I've inserted the lines:

```
const mod = 'E9Y4qtFXK2qQGAGq3'; // this is the userId of the account that I wish to make admin
Roles.addUsersToRoles(mod, 'moderator');
```

Then, instead of just displaying all the tasks, I enclose the command to display all tasks in an if-statement:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId,'moderator')) {
     Meteor.publish('tasks', function tasksPublication() {
     return Tasks.find();
    });
  }
}
```

This should display all tasks if you are logged in as the moderator/admin, and nothing otherwise. But when I run this code, no tasks show up even when I am logged in as the admin. I am certain that the userId I set is correct, and that there are tasks in the collection. Does anyone have any ideas of what the problem might be?

(Or, any other suggestions on how to do this? Doesn't have to use alanning-roles -- I just thought that would be simplest)

Thanks so much
-C

EDIT: If I replace "this.userId" with "mod" in the line:

```
if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId,'moderator')){...}
```

then all the tasks appear. So it appears that the problem is with the output of this.userId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move where you are checking if current user is a 'moderator' to inside the publish function:

Currently in your code, when you access `this.userId` the server is starting up, and `this.userId` will be `undefined`.  So the code in your `if` statement is not being executed, so the `publish` function is not created, and no clients will be able to subscribe to this data.

Try this:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('tasks', function tasksPublication() {
        if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'moderator')) {
            return Tasks.find({});
        } 
  });
}
```

Now, on startup the `Meteor.isServer` block runs, creating the `tasks` publication, with the code to check the role inside it.  This function will now be called every time a client subscribes to it, and in this context `this.userId` will be the current client's user ID.

Also, don't place the alanning-roles package's source code in your app's folders - include the package either by running `meteor add alanning:roles`, or via npm with `npm install @alanning/roles --save`

Answer (score 0):

You should use Meteor.userId() instead of this.userId:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(),'moderator')) {
   Meteor.publish('tasks', function tasksPublication() {
     return Tasks.find();
    });
  }
}
```

As as rule of thumb, always use Meteor.userId(), except inside a publication, where you should use this.userId